# How do I create a custom exclusion strategy for JMS Serializer that allows me to make run-time decisions about whether to include a particular field?

Tags: symfony, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

As the title says, I am trying to make a run-time decision on whether or not to include fields in the serialization. In my case, this decision will be based on permissions.

I am using Symfony 2, so what I'm looking to do is add an additional annotation called @ExcludeIf which accepts a security expression.

I can handle the annotation parsing and storing of the meta data, but I am not able to see how to integrate a custom exclusion strategy with the library.

Any suggestions?

Note: exclusion strategies are an actual construct in the JMS codebase, I just haven't been able to figure out the best way to integrate an extra on top of the others

PS: I had asked about this before and was pointed to using groups. For various reasons this is a very poor solution for my needs.

Comment: You could use a custom subscribing handler for your specific object that allows or removes specified items. See http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/handlers

Comment: From what I can tell, this won't allow me to skip a field. I could set it to null at best, but that isn't semantically the same and not what I want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just have to create a class that implements `JMS\Serializer\Exclusion\ExclusionStrategyInterface`

```
<?php

namespace JMS\Serializer\Exclusion;

use JMS\Serializer\Metadata\ClassMetadata;
use JMS\Serializer\Metadata\PropertyMetadata;
use JMS\Serializer\Context;

interface ExclusionStrategyInterface
{
    /**
     * Whether the class should be skipped.
     *
     * @param ClassMetadata $metadata
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function shouldSkipClass(ClassMetadata $metadata, Context $context);

    /**
     * Whether the property should be skipped.
     *
     * @param PropertyMetadata $property
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function shouldSkipProperty(PropertyMetadata $property, Context $context);
}
```

In your case, you can implement your own custom logic in the `shouldSkipProperty` method and always return `false` for `shouldSkipClass`.

Example of implementation can be found in the [JMS/Serializer repository](https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/tree/master/src/JMS/Serializer/Exclusion)

We will reference the created service as `acme.my_exclusion_strategy_service` below.

---

In your controller action:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use JMS\Serializer\SerializationContext;

// ....

$context = SerializationContext::create()
    ->addExclusionStrategy($this->get('acme.my_exclusion_strategy_service'));

$serial = $this->get('jms_serializer')->serialize($object, 'json', $context);

return new Response($serial, Response::HTTP_OK, array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'));
```

Or if you are using FOSRestBundle

```
<?php

use FOS\RestBundle\View;
use JMS\Serializer\SerializationContext;

// ....

$context = SerializationContext::create()
    ->addExclusionStrategy($this->get('acme.my_exclusion_strategy_service'))

$view = new View($object);
$view->setSerializationContext($context);

// or you can create your own view factory that handles the creation
// of the context for you

return $this->get('fos_rest.view_handler')->handle($view);
```

Comment: Thanks! I had figured it out, thankfully, but I should have came back to update the question.

Comment: JMS\Serializer\Context is an abstract class so it cannot be instantiated as shown in your example.
There's also no example whatsoever of the "acme.my_exclusion_strategy_service"

Comment: @Nicolas Thank you for pointing out the error about SerializationContext ! I've fixed it and add some clarifications. I won't provide an example of implementation of the interface since this is pretty straight forward (what is not trivial is the associated custom logic). Nevertheless you can look at [GroupsExclusionStrategy](https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/blob/master/src/JMS/Serializer/Exclusion/GroupsExclusionStrategy.php) that is provided by JMS for example

Comment: The logic I referred to in this question originally was implemented in the following: https://github.com/jmcclell/JLMSerializerExpression

Its usage is made more clear in the associated Symfony Bundle: https://github.com/jmcclell/JLMSerializerExpressionBundle

Answer (score 4):

As of `jms/serializer` 1.4.0, the symfony expression language is integrated in its core.

The feature is documented at http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/cookbook/exclusion_strategies#dynamic-exclusion-strategy and this allows to use runtime exclusion strategies.

An example taken from the documentation is:

```
class MyObject
{
    /**
     * @Exclude(if="service('user_manager_service').getSomeRuntimeData(object)")
     */
    private $name;

   /**
     * @Expose(if="service('request_stack').getCurrent().has('foo')")
     */
    private $name2;
}
```

I this example, the services `user_manager_service` and `request_stack` are invoked at runtime, and depending on the return (`true` or `false`), the property will be exposed  or not.

With the same expression language, as of 1.6.0 is possible also to use virtual properties via expression language. 
Documented at http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#virtualproperty allows to add on the fly data coming from external services

Comment: I'm happy the concept became first-class! Thank you for the update on the current library state.

Comment: This answer worked for me with a small change :) @Expose(if="service('request_stack').getCurrentRequest().query.has('foo')")