# @JMS\Exclude only if a property is empty

Tags: symfony, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

I am using JMS\Serializer in my project and I want to ignore one property only if the array in it is empty.

I tried something like :

```
@JMS\Exclude(if="count('$this->required') === 0")
or 
@JMS\Exclude(if="empty('required')")
```

but got a syntax error.

Can anyone help me on this?

thank.

Comment: as far as i can read the docs you can use `@JMS\Exclude(if="<1")` , could you try ?

Comment: if not try the "exclusionStrategy" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21916450/how-do-i-create-a-custom-exclusion-strategy-for-jms-serializer-that-allows-me-to

Comment: What you need was implemented recently and it is in release-1.7 so you might as well wait for [it](https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/releases). It is called [@SkipWhenEmpty](https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/pull/757/files#diff-9828fde36b4c4800e1d437a28538de94R35) This is the [bug](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle/issues/373) related it. "`@SkipWhenEmpty` This annotation can be defined on a
property to indicate that the property should not be serialized if the
result will be 'empty'".

Comment: oh thank @BentCoder. it's exactly what I need. i hop it will be merged soon.

Comment: @MathieuDelisle I added it as an answer below so if you could kindly accept it, everybody else would have an idea of the possible solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need was implemented recently and it is in release-1.7 so you might as well wait for [it](https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/releases). It is called [@SkipWhenEmpty](https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/pull/757/files#diff-9828fde36b4c4800e1d437a28538de94R35)

> @SkipWhenEmpty This annotation can be defined on a property to
>   indicate that the property should not be serialized if the result will
>   be "empty".

This is the [bug](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle/issues/373) related it.

Answer (score 2):

You need this one:

```
@JMS\Exclude(if="!object.required")
```